# What parts of the kernel are not namespace aware?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, docker, namespace, container

I've started to learn Docker security, and so have come across cgroups, namespaces, and capabilities, which together with `chroot` form the basis of modern container technologies.

Historically many container vulnerabilities have been exploited by abusing parts of the kernel that are not namespace aware from userspace, e.g. by reading/writing files under `/proc` like `modprobe`.

I'm familiar with the concept of namespaces, but I'm not sure of when the boundary of namespaces stops to apply, so that code may execute in the root namespace instead of the user's namespace?

Comment: Namespaces don’t separate root from users. Could you clarify what you mean in the last paragraph?

Comment: I think that root name space means the host/default namespace. And user namespace means a non-default namespace. Is that correct?

Comment: @StephenKitt- by root namespace, I mean the initial namespace created on the host, containing the real root user. Other user namespaces will also contain root users, but they will be mapped to ordinary users in the root namespace, normally by adding a constant slide to their UID. Does that answer your question?

Comment: "I'm familiar with the concept of namespaces". No, you're not

Answer (score 1):

A vulnerability, but not of the type you mention.

A user that can create and run an arbitrary docker container, can create a container with a mapped part of the host file-system. They can then in the container, running as root create a setuid root program on disk. Then from the host, they can run this to gain root privileges.

Comment: This would be improved by links to relevant kernel bugs or demonstrations of this vulnerability.

Comment: Shouldn't the user namespace map the root inside the container to an ordinary user on the host, so that the setuid binary won't be owned by root?

Comment: Maybe they can. Maybe they won't (Which would you do, if you were trying to attack a system).

Comment: I tried this with the default docker installation on MacOS, and can confirm it works. Root inside the container namespace is indeed root in the host by default, and the setuid bit can be set in a bind mount.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good but very difficult to answer question because it is very open.

Focusing on the "code may execute in the root namespace" part, it depends on what you mean by "code":

- The userspace part should be isolated even without namespaces. I.e. all the code that you write is executed separately from everything else, regardless of namespaces
- The kernel itself, when invoked via syscalls, always has access to everything (unless it's a VM itself). That means that the kernel parts are not isolated in any way. [1]

What #2 above means is that they are namespace-aware through per-process abstractions. I.e. their entry in the process table points to the namespaced parts (e.g. the root filesystem), either directly or indirectly. From that point on, as long as something at the kernel-side works, it should be "isolated" because it will always be accessing the right set of data.

This however doesn't mean that bugs cannot affect all aspects of the running system, including other containers.

If you want to run something in an isolated system then you need a full blown VM or user space linux. Containers are meant to isolate processes and what they see and can access. When there's a bug then they can go beyond their restrictions just like normal process can end up running code as root.

[1] Almost everything that has to do with the system is done using syscalls. E.g. opening a file, writing to a socket, sending a signal, etc.

Comment: By root namespace, I mean the initial user namespace created by the kernel. When you write "The userspace part should be isolated..." - do you mean from kernelspace? So, all syscalls are namespace aware? Also, do syscalls have entries in the process table? The root file system is in the mount namespace?